# How can I display a d3 graph with angularjs and coffescript?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, yeoman

I am trying to draw a d3 graphic with an angularjs directive coded in coffeescript, but I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5221:38
```

I also use return $compile(scope)

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9BX6/)**

Comment: Show us some code or better make a plunk (here)[http://plnkr.co/edit/4gwEcINxuTd3dEcBKotB]

Comment: This is the code in CoffeeScript

http://jsfiddle.net/U9BX6/